# Difference between DCnet and mixnet in terms of forwarding anonymity?

Tags: anonymity, mixnets

It seems that with both anonymous communication protocols we can achieve some level of forwarding anonymity, however, is one protocol better than the other in this respect? It seems that they both offer the same level of anonymity with different drawbacks:

- Mixnets are vulnerable to replay attacks which can allow attackers to trace the origin of messages, potentially breaking key encryption schemes, or compromise the mix server.
- DC-nets seem to be more robust since they aren't affected by the same attacks as mixnets, but they are more vulnerable to attackers attempting to cause intentional collisions.

It seems that dc-nets achieve better forward anonymity at the expense of potential collisions and computational expensive messages since they have to be XORed by every node in the system. Is this a good assumption or am I missing some key info?